# How to show the last item in the List View when scrolled to get new items dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view in my app which shows 10 items initially, and when i scroll to the bottom, it dynamically adds 10 items every time. My problem is when i scroll to the bottom, the display goes to the 1st item in the list(not the newly added 10 items), so i need to scroll all the way down.

I used

```
ListView.setSelection(totalItemCount - 9);
```

to display the 1st item of the newly added 10 items. But here what happens is the display goes to the 1st item of the listview actually, but again it automatically scrolls to the 1st item of the newly added 10 items. so, the ux will be bad here....i want it to change so that it whould not go to the top of the listview. hope i explained it clearly, please help, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll down and start getting new data you should store your Last Visible Position in some variables using this method :

```
int firstVisiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

**Edit** 
Try this :

```
View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
int distFromTop = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
```

Then after you completed loading data you should set this position using :

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisiblePosition, distFromTop);
```

Comment: yeah that is how i am implementing right now.....what happens here is it 1st goes to the top and then comes to the setSelection(firstVisiblePosition)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna override onSizeChanged(...) method of your listview.

I guess thats were it navigates to its top.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
setSelection(getCount()-9);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting the selection manually is a good user experience(since they could be viewing the top items on the list).

Once you have dynamically retrieved the new set of items that are to be added to the list you could simply call the addAll() method and then notify the adapter that the content needs to be refreshed using notifyDatasetChanged(). Listviews are smart about remembering the current position on a refresh.

Comment: yeah I am using addAll() and noifyDataSetChanged()