# Android List View First show 10 items and then add more items when we scroll

Tags: android

Under this link [How to show the last item in the List View when scrolled to get new items dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612670/how-to-show-the-last-item-in-the-list-view-when-scrolled-to-get-new-items-dynami), someone has posted that  "I have a list view in my app which shows 10 items initially, and when i scroll to the bottom, it dynamically adds 10 items every time"

Can you please post the code to implement this, as I also need the same in my android app.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Use scroll listener to add 10 more items each time

Comment: Thanks for information, but I am very new to android, I have built up an application in which my listview get data from database, I need to first show 10 items and then show other items on scrolling over the list view.. Can you please post the code for it, so that It can help me..

Comment: [Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html) is a good sample you can get idea

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            islast = totalItemCount > 2 && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount;



            if(islast && !loding){

                loding = true; // if add item in other thread.
                //add item process
                //and adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loding = false;
            }
        }
```

refer this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Can you please tell me one more thing that how can I call this function after doing listView.setAdapter(adapter); in activity's onCreate method..

Comment: listView.setOnScrollListener(new onScrollLisenter(){
//override method onScroll, onScrollStateChange.
})

and put log and check working.

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out how to implement OnScrollListener but how can I limit the visibleItemCount to 10 records at first view and how will I load the next 10 items on scroll.. Can you please help me here a bit more..

Comment: my english skill is not good...
please edit your hole code above your question.
it some vague. not your code i can't explain how to do.